# I'm a stay-at-home person—but who <or whom> isn't these days?

Tags: objective-case, subjective

Should I be using "who" or "whom" in this sentence?

How would I form the deep structure of this sentence?

Is it "These days, a stay at home person is not whom"?

Comment: Simplify to say 'One person ignores the stay-at-home advice. _Who is it?_ / _Whom is it_?' // And compare with 'Who/m is there?'

Comment: "These days, a stay at home person is not who(m)" is particularly difficult to digest and would, IMHO, be better phrased as "Who isn't a stay-at-home person these days?"

Comment: Thanks @Phil W. Disregarding convention, I'm looking for what is technically correct and in accordance with Standard Written English. Is it technically correct to write "Whom isn't a stay-at-home person these days"?

Comment: NO, it is not correct. You need a subject pronoun....and I don'r understand what you mean by "Disregarding convention" and "technically correct ".

Comment: Thanks, @Cascabel. Please, can you expand on that?

Comment: The answers in the dupe are quite clear. Some are more wordy than others, but basically 1) If the pronoun needed by the verb is a subject, use _who_   2) If the pronoun is the object of the a) a verb or a b) a preposition, use _whom_.  3) Forget #2a. Figuring out when to use _whom_ is not worth the time. Use only _who_, or risk sounding like a pompous twit.